# Ruby-newbie Active Record query / model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Here is roughly what I have:

I have many companies that has many user through roles:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :roles
end
```

and many users which can have many companies through roles:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :comapnies, :through => :roles
end
```

and many roles that bind the two together:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
end
```

The idea here is that a user can sign-in through a common email username and then have privileges assigned to each company.  Role has a user_id and company_id keys along with a privilege column 'user_role' (i.e. guest, user, admin etc.).

Here is where being ruby-newbie fails me.  When my user logs in I want to query which companies they have privileges on and switch that on the fly with a menu drop down.  So they login and are active in 'Company A' and then they can switch to 'Company B'.  When they switch the company_id is stored in a session variable (I already have their user_id stored with a functioning authentication system).

What is the best way to query this?  I have a user_id and I want to retrieve a list of the company_id, company_name, 'user_role' etc.  then use this to generate a pop-down list.

I have been playing with the console trying `Role.Company.etc.etc` but can't seem to figure this out.  When I was doing this in PHP / MySQL before it would have been a complex join query. I am sure it's easier in Rails I jet can't seem to figure it out.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: couldn't you do something like `for company in current_user.companies` to do a list. To test to see if you have the scope handled correctly, you could just throw in `<% if current_user? %>` `<%= current_user.companies %>` `<% end %>` in one of your views

Comment: This of course assumes that your authentication uses current_user when they login.

Comment: @kobaltz It's bad form to trigger SQL queries in the view, so maybe would have been better to just show how to retrieve the companies in the action.

Comment: so in your controller, it would be something like @companies = current_user.companies

Comment: Is current_user the integer value of my users id or the actual user object?. I already have an application helper method current_user that gets the session stored user id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all of the companies a user has access to (for any role) via `current_user.companies.uniq`. The `uniq` part just ensures you don't have duplicate companies in the list (in the case a user has more than one role for a single company).

Comment: Ok... I get it now.  I ran the console and set current_user  `current_user = User.find(1)` and then ran `current_user.companies` and it got what I was looking for.  I actually had the 'companies' spelled wrong in one of my model relations which was half the problem.

Comment: Now... the question I have is how can I add the role to the results.  example `Company A:Guest, Company B:Admin, etc.`.  I get running my `current_user.companies` results through a for loop to make a simple list but can't seem to figure this second part out.

Comment: `@companies = @user.companies.include(:roles)` then `@companies.each { |company| "#{company.role.name} of #{company.name}" }` — however, this is starting to violate the Law of Demeter (google it), so you would want to start refactor things like `company.role.name` to `company.role_name` through a delegation (in the Company model): `delegate :name, :to => :role, :prefix => :role`.

Comment: Can you expand the full login here on `@companies.each { |company| "#{company.role.name} of #{company.name}" }`?

Here is what I have now 

`<% current_user_companies.each do |company| %>
<li><a href="/companies/<%= company.id %>"><% if company.id == 1 %><i class="icon-ok"></i><% end %><%= company.name %></a></li>
<% end %>`

I have it looping through a list and the company name is displayed.  I am looking for the company name and the role i.e. "Stackoverlow (Admin)", "ABC Ltd. (Guest)".  When I add the includes() it runs fails on `NoMethodError: undefined method `roles'`

Comment: Why are you forming links manually? You seem like you're missing a lot of basic Rails knowledge…a trip back to the Guides might be worthwhile.

Comment: I know... I am being lazy ;).  I have will have to clean up the code once I get the logic sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyones feedback.  This got me looking at includes and joins again.  I ended up looking at http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins and the Rails API docs and cobbled together this:

`Role.includes(:company).where(:user_id => session[:user_id])`

I then loop through @role and I can pull role.role_name and role.company.name etc.  Starting the query with the User.find(session[:user_id]) was complicating it.